# JAVA: Putting alternative ( || ) in loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops, checkbox, jbutton

I have a quick question. I want to make my code shorter and I'm wondering whether I can put in some way below checkboxes into loop. The sense of this part of code is to enable "Find" button in case when at least one of checkbox is selected. Thank you in advance for every tip.

```
    if (checkBoxes[0].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[1].isSelected() == true
            || checkBoxes[2].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[3].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[4].isSelected() == true
            || checkBoxes[5].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[6].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[7].isSelected() == true
            || checkBoxes[8].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[9].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[10].isSelected() == true
            || checkBoxes[11].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[12].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[13].isSelected() == true
            || checkBoxes[14].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[15].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[16].isSelected() == true
            || checkBoxes[17].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[18].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[19].isSelected() == true
            || checkBoxes[20].isSelected() == true || checkBoxes[21].isSelected() == true) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Note that all of those `== true` are completely unnecessary (and potentially harmful). You **already** have a boolean (the one returned by `isSelected`), you don't need a comparison to give you another one. When testing booleans, test them directly: `if (boolValue)` and `if (!boolValue)`. (The potential harm comes from when you are checking a variable and forget one of the `=`: `if (variable = true)` which *sets* the variable to `true` and then branches into the if block.)

Comment: Wouldn't this be better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as the OP currently explains it, the code is working. Help for this problem could be asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for(int i=0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if(checkBoxes[i].isSelected()) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can :

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length && !found; i++) {
    found = checkBoxes[i].isSelected();
}
if (found) {
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

or you can avoid the `boolean` variable and break out of the loop when you find the first selected checkbox :

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) { // you can also replace this with enhanced
                                              // for loop
    if (checkBoxes[i].isSelected()) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first example is quite nice. I'd also suggest using `button.setEnabled(found);`.

Answer (score 6):

Why not to use `stream`?

```
if (Arrays.stream(checkBoxes).anyMatch(checkbox -> checkbox.isSelected())) {
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you have an array of course you can use a loop.

Here is a version with an enhanced loop :

```
for (Checkbox checkBox : checkBoxes){
   if (checkBox.isSelected()){
      button.setEnabled(true);
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Boolean j = false;
for (byte i = 0; i <= 21)
    if (checkBoxes[i].isSelected() == true) {
        j = true;
        break;
        if (j == true) {
            //your code
        }
```

you van use this code
it is so easy

Comment: `for (byte i = 0; i <= 21; )` It will lead to an infinitive loop. `i` is always less than 21. And it is not incremented anywhere. And it is better to use `checkBoxes.length` while iterating.  If a checkbox is added or removed. you will have to update your `for-loop`  condition.

Comment: this is true now